# line by line execute twice in VS 2017 c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

now i run my MVC project and this is my code

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public virtual ActionResult Create(PurchaseHead ph, int Id)
    {{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {

                try
                {
                    ph.InputDate = ConvertDate.PersianToGregorian(ph.InputDate.ToString());
                    ph.PurchaseData = ConvertDate.PersianToGregorian(ph.PurchaseData.ToString());
                    ph.CustomerId = Id;
                    _db.PurchaseHeads.Add(ph);
                    ViewBag.Records = "Name : " + ph.InputDate + " City:  ";
                    ViewBag.Currentdate = ConvertDate.GregoriantoPersian(DateTime.Now);
                    ViewBag.ShowBody = true;
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                    var custommer = _db.Customers.Find(Id);
                    ViewBag.Customer = custommer;
                    ph.Customer = custommer;
                    var pb = _db.PurchaseBodies.Include(x => x.ItemId).Include(h => h.UnitId);
                    //return PartialView("Create",ph);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "PurchaseBodies");

                    //RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }

            }


        }
        return View();
    }
```

when i run my project all code run twice, i set a break point in lines,  debugger run each line twice not run many line twice or not run one block twice. i don't know why?
***new in edit*** :

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "PurchaseHead", new { id = custom.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "referDiv" }))
{

    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="ذخیره" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>}
```

Comment: what is the Action calling your code?

Comment: '
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "PurchaseHead", new { id = custom.Id }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "referDiv" }))
    {  <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="ذخیره" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>}'

Comment: The first step is to find out whether the *request* is happening twice.  You do this using the Developer tools in IE/Edge or Chrome/FF.  You look at the network requests and see if there are 2x the number of requests.  You can also look at the IIS logs and see if there are two requests.